# Use a variable read from an Xml and use it to search an element from another xml with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

this is snpdate.xml

```
<skata serial="GSI100-A-00103"/>
```

this is the test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Clients xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <set>
    <indexlist>
        <index name="mario1" sn="GSI100-A-00100" status="ok" version="v49" />
        <index name="mario2" sn="GSI100-A-00101" status="ok" version="v49" />
        <index name="mario3" sn="GSI100-A-00102" status="ok" version="v49" />
        <index name="mario4" sn="GSI100-A-00103" status="OFF" version="v49" />
        <index name="mario5" sn="GSI100-A-00104" status="ok" version="v49" />
        <index name="mario6" sn="GSI100-A-00105" status="ok" version="v49" />
        <index name="mario7" sn="GSI100-A-00106" status="ok" version="v49" />
    </indexlist>
    </set>
    </Clients>
```

---

```
$xmloff = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xmlold = "C:\Program Files (x86)\GSI\Atreus\snupdate.xml" 
$xmledit = "C:\Users\bigadmin\Desktop\Projects\AutoUpdate\test.xml"
[xml]$Xmlsn = Get-Content($xmlold) -Encoding UTF8    #open 1st xml
[xml]$Xmlnew = Get-Content($xmledit) -Encoding UTF8  #open 2st xml

$you = $Xmlsn.SelectSingleNode("//skata/@serial") #get value of serial element
$you.Value #prints correct value


$attr = $Xmlnew.SelectSingleNode("//Clients/set/indexlist/index[@sn='$you']/@status")
#from the second xml trying to get the value of status based on sn taking #the variable of $you. returns null.instead of OFF. if i manually insert   
#[@sn='GSI100-A-00103'] instead of "$you" i get the correct result.    

 $attr.Value
```

From the second xml I am trying to get the value of status based on sn, taking the variable of `$you`. It returns null instead of OK. If I manually insert
`[@sn='GSI100-A-00103']` instead of `$you` I get the correct result.
I want to take `$you` variable with value `f.e.GSI100-A-00103` and use it on another xml to find a new element value with status = off. I think the problem is that the variable is loaded from the other xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare `sn` to the string `$you.Value` rather than the XmlAttribute `$you`. Since you need to retrieve a value of a property inside of a quoted string, the `$()` operator is used.

```
$attr = $Xmlnew.SelectSingleNode("//Clients/set/indexlist/index[@sn='$($you.Value)']/@status")
```

**Explanation:**

When retrieving properties of an object inside of a string, variable expansion stops at the `.` character. These situations require the use of the subexpression operator `$()`. The operator tells the PowerShell parser to re-evaluate the parsing mode based on the `.` character instead of treating the `.propertyname` as a literal string.

You can see this in the example below:

```
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{"Property" = "Value"}
"$obj.property"   # Unexpected Results
@{Property=Value}.property

"$($obj.property)"  # Expected Results
Value
```

Here is [Microsoft's Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6) on the subexpression operator.